# The best way configurate identity server 5.1.0 as LDAP server and test the connection

Tags: java, server, ldap, wso2-identity-server

How can I configurate the identity server to work as LDAP server? how can I test the ldap server with connection  (in java) to create and authenticate users?
I read the documentation but its not clear.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First of all Identity Server is not a LDAP server or it cannot work as a LDAP server. It can use LDAP (or Active Directory or relational databases) as its user stores. It comes with a pre configured LDAP as its primary user store. Documentation at [1] describes how to change the primary user store and configure secondary user stores. If you want to use the built in LDAP you don't have to bother about those configurations.

For user authentication you can use several protocols. First of all you need to configure a service provider as described in [2]. In the beginning you can focus only on the "Inbound authentication configuration" of. In this part you have to select a protocol for authentication such as SAML, OAuth, etc.. For authentication with SAML, you can use sample web application and configurations done at [3].

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/Configuring+User+Stores
[2] https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/Configuring+a+Service+Provider
[3] https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/Configuring+Single+Sign-On